# Find difference of timestamps in a column based on other column in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table like below in `Hive`.

I want to calculate the time difference in `seconds` for columns where `id` is same and get the value in `time_diff` column.

`Table`

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| id  |  event  |            eventdate   |time_diff  |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 2   | sent    | 2017-11-23 04:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 1   | click   | 2017-11-24 03:49:50.0  | NULL      |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
```

`expected result`

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| id  |  event  |            eventdate   |time_diff  |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 2   | sent    | 2017-11-23 04:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 1   | click   | 2017-11-24 03:49:50.0  | 86391     |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
```

I have done like below manually

```
SELECT (unix_timestamp('2017-11-24 03:49:50.0') - unix_timestamp('2017-11-23 03:49:59.0'));
```

I am getting the value as `86391` but I am unable to figure out how to do this when both `id` are same

How can I get the expected result

> edit

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| id  |  event  |            eventdate   |time_diff  |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:50.0  | 0         |
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 2   | sent    | 2017-11-23 04:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 1   | click   | 2017-11-24 03:49:50.0  | NULL      |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What's the time_diff for the click now? Still 86391? Are sent events after the initial one effectively ignored?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 The `click` has `86391` in `time_diff` column but the second `sent` records where id is `1` is having `time_diff` as `9` I wnat that to be `0` only. Irrespective of what we do I want all the `sent` events to have `time_diff` column to be `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Largely duplicating previous answer but I think it's worth highlighting the manual:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, event VARCHAR(8), eventdate timestamp);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'sent', '2017-11-23 03:49:50.0');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'sent', '2017-11-23 03:49:59.0');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'sent', '2017-11-23 04:49:59.0');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'click', '2017-11-24 03:49:50.0');

SELECT
    id
,   event
,   eventdate
,   CASE WHEN event = 'sent'
    THEN 0
    ELSE
        unix_timestamp(eventdate) - MIN(unix_timestamp(eventdate))
            OVER (PARTITION BY id)
    END AS time_diff
FROM test;

+------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| id   | event | eventdate           | time_diff |
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
|    1 | sent  | 2017-11-23 03:49:50 |         0 |
|    1 | sent  | 2017-11-23 03:49:59 |         0 |
|    1 | click | 2017-11-24 03:49:50 |     86400 |
|    2 | sent  | 2017-11-23 04:49:59 |         0 |
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I went `MIN()` based on experience with this sort of contact / response data and the likelihood of multiple click events and the assumption that `time_diff` should be relative to the initial sent event. Clearly the windowing function can be adjusted as needed.

Comment: Is there a way Can I make sure that all the `sent` have `time_diff` to `0`. When I try your answer I get expected result but in some real data I get the `time_diff` for `sent` different numbers. i want to make sure `time_diff` for `sent` is always zero. Like in your comment Here I will have many   `sent` events for the same `id` .

Comment: Can you add representative data to the example with expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LAG` with window function to make it.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  id int,
  event varchar(50),
  eventdate datetime
);




insert into T values (1,'sent', '2017-11-23 03:49:59.0');
insert into T values (2,'sent', '2017-11-23 04:49:59.0');
insert into T values (1,'click', '2017-11-24 03:49:50.0');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *, 
   coalesce(unix_timestamp(eventdate) - unix_timestamp(LAG(eventdate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY eventdate)),0) time_diff
FROM T;

| id  | event | eventdate           | time_diff |
| --- | ----- | ------------------- | --------- |
| 1   | sent  | 2017-11-23 03:49:59 | 0         |
| 1   | click | 2017-11-24 03:49:50 | 86391     |
| 2   | sent  | 2017-11-23 04:49:59 | 0         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/utpQPCRUmTgPGbA1W7orm9/1)